# How to purchase for the first time an In-App Purchases Subscription in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, google-play-console, in-app-subscription

I am trying to implement a subscription system in my Flutter app with the [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) package. All I found in the documentation is that I need an old purchase to handle the subscription:

```
final PurchaseDetails oldPurchaseDetails = ...;
PurchaseParam purchaseParam = PurchaseParam(
    productDetails: productDetails,
    changeSubscriptionParam: ChangeSubscriptionParam(
        oldPurchaseDetails: oldPurchaseDetails,
        prorationMode: ProrationMode.immediateWithTimeProration));
InAppPurchaseConnection.instance
    .buyNonConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam);
```

I already have the productDetails.
How can I subscribe to it for the first time?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an old subscription to subscribe for the first time, the parameter `changeSubscriptionParam` is optional and you can pass null for it. When you are going to change the subscription, you will need to pass the old subscription in this parameter in the `changeSubscriptionParam`
parameter. This is only needed for android and a simple way to do get the old subscription is (in my case there are only two possible signatures):

```dart
    Future<GooglePlayPurchaseDetails> _getOld() async {

      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
            final InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition androidAddition =
                _inAppPurchase
                    .getPlatformAddition<InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition>();
            QueryPurchaseDetailsResponse oldPurchaseDetailsQuery =
                await androidAddition.queryPastPurchases();
            oldPurchaseDetailsQuery.pastPurchases.forEach((element) {
              oldPurchaseDetails = element;
            });
          }

      return oldPurchaseDetails;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in 2023 i am using [in_app_purchase: ^3.1.11](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) it is best for in app purchase flutter package.

i do it with [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) state-management

show **pubspec.yaml**

```
  in_app_purchase: ^3.1.11              #use latest
  in_app_purchase_android: ^0.3.0+15    #use latest
```

add this **implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:6.0.1'**
line in <android/app/build.gradle> location in dependencies

**Like this way**

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:6.0.1' // use latest version
}
```

Do not forget to add following permission in your manifest (AndroidManifest.xml)

```
    <!-- Internet -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- InAppPurchase -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

i just make simple provider class for complete solution of in app purchase.
also i provide right information what i did.

```
class SubscriptionProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final InAppPurchase _inAppPurchase = InAppPurchase.instance;

  //! Private variables
  bool _available = false;
  List<ProductDetails> _products = [];
  List<PurchaseDetails> _purchases = [];
  StreamSubscription<List<PurchaseDetails>>? _subscription;
  bool _isLoading = false;
  // final StreamController<StreamSubscription<List<PurchaseDetails>>> _processCompletionController = StreamController<StreamSubscription<List<PurchaseDetails>>>();
  final StreamController<Stream<List<PurchaseDetails>>> _processCompletionController = StreamController<Stream<List<PurchaseDetails>>>();


  //! Getters

  //! used for loading until process competition
  bool get isLoading => _isLoading;
  //! If we want use stream outside of this provider we can used it
  //! but used here or there not both side
  //! for best state-management we used inside this provider class
  Stream<Stream<List<PurchaseDetails>>> get subscription => _processCompletionController.stream;
  //! isAvailable provide boolean for is product available or not
  bool get isAvailable => _available;
  List<ProductDetails> get productDetails => _products;
  List<PurchaseDetails> get purchaseDetails => _purchases;
  //! This 'isActive' bool will provider my plan is active or not in anywhere in any screen
  Future<bool> get isActive async => await _isSubscriptionActive();

  //! Find product are available in store or not
  //! this method will called onetime for trigger stream and get details about
  //! available product
  Future<void> purchaseInit() async {
    try {
      _purchaseStream();
      _isLoading = true;
      notifyListeners();
      _available = await _inAppPurchase.isAvailable();
      debugPrint('_available : $_available');
      notifyListeners();
      final productIDs = <String>{'product_id_1','product_id_2','product_id_3'}; // your productIDs
      debugPrint('productIDs : $productIDs');
      List<ProductDetails> products = await _getProducts(productIDs);
      _products = products;
      _isSubscriptionActive();
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
      debugPrint('catchError : $e');
    }
  }

   //! This stream will triggered every time when any change will occur in purchase plan,
  //! or user will buy/restore purchase plan

  StreamSubscription<List<PurchaseDetails>> _purchaseStream() {
    final Stream<List<PurchaseDetails>> purchaseUpdate = _inAppPurchase.purchaseStream;
    _subscription = purchaseUpdate.listen(
      (purchaseDetailsList) {
        _listenToPurchaseUpdated(purchaseDetailsList);
        _purchases = purchaseDetailsList;
        notifyListeners();
      },
      onDone: () {
        _subscription?.cancel();
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Done");
      },
      onError: (_) {
        _subscription?.cancel();
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Error : $_");
      },
    );
    notifyListeners();

    
    _processCompletionController.sink.add(purchaseUpdate);
    return _subscription!;
  }

    //! This function will provide products with details
    //! If no product available then list provide empty list

  Future<List<ProductDetails>> _getProducts(Set<String> productIDs) async {
    ProductDetailsResponse response = await _inAppPurchase.queryProductDetails(productIDs);
    debugPrint('_getProductsError : ${response.error}');
    debugPrint('response : ${response.productDetails}');
    return response.productDetails;
  }


  // ! This function will call from outside for buy product
  // ! whichever purchasePlan/product want to buy will passed as function argument
  // ! if user/consumer/customer buy our any purchase plan then this will true otherwise false
  // ! Must Note : in below function autoConsume = false for android and true for ios

  Future<bool> buyProduct({required ProductDetails product}) async {
    final PurchaseParam purchaseParam = PurchaseParam(productDetails: product);
    final bool isSuccess = await _inAppPurchase.buyConsumable(
      purchaseParam: purchaseParam,
      autoConsume: false, // False for android True for IOS
    );

    debugPrint('buyProduct : isSuccess => $isSuccess');
    return isSuccess;
  }

  //! In case of app uninstalled or something happening then
  //! if plan is still active so user no need to buy new plan
  //! user can restore previous plan if exist and still active
  //! This function also called from outside for restoring purpose
  //! in below method 'response.pastPurchases.isEmpty' is true thats mean no plan is active
  //! base on that you can move ahead in your app

  Future restorePlan() async {
    debugPrint('restorePlan');
    await _inAppPurchase.restorePurchases();
    final response = await _inAppPurchase.getPlatformAddition<InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition>().queryPastPurchases();

    if (response.pastPurchases.isEmpty) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "You haven't any restore plan");
    }
  }

  void _listenToPurchaseUpdated(List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) {
    purchaseDetailsList.forEach(
      (PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async {
        debugPrint('_status : ${purchaseDetails.status}');
        debugPrint('_Error  : ${purchaseDetails.error}');
        switch (purchaseDetails.status) {
          case PurchaseStatus.canceled:
            {
              Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "You cancelled payment");
            }
            break;
          case PurchaseStatus.pending:
            {
              Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Your subscription plan is pending");
            }
            break;
          case PurchaseStatus.purchased:
            {
              Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "You purchase plan successfully");
              
            }
            break;
          case PurchaseStatus.restored:
            {
              // Restore purchases, if applicable.
              final response = await _inAppPurchase.getPlatformAddition<InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition>().queryPastPurchases();
              if (response.pastPurchases.isNotEmpty) {
              
               await _inAppPurchase.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
                Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Your plan restore successfully");

                
             
                
              }
            }
            break;
          case PurchaseStatus.error:
            {
              debugPrint('----Error : ${purchaseDetails.error}');
              debugPrint('----msg   : ${purchaseDetails.error?.message}');
              if (purchaseDetails.error!.message == "BillingResponse.itemAlreadyOwned") {
                Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "You already purchased this plan");
                Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2, milliseconds: 200), () => Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Try to restore your plan"));
              } else if (purchaseDetails.error!.message == "BillingResponse.developerError") {
                Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: purchaseDetails.error?.details);
              } else if (purchaseDetails.error!.message == "BillingResponse.itemUnavailable") {
                Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Selected plan is unavailable");
              }
            }
            break;
          default:
            {
              Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Something went wrong! please try again");
            }
            break;
        }

        debugPrint('====> purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase : ${purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase}');
        if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase) {
          await _inAppPurchase.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
          //StoreData locally
          final encode = SubscriptionsInfo.toJson(purchaseDetails);
          sharedPref.subscriptionInfo = encodeSubscriptionInfo(SubscriptionsInfo.fromJson(encode));
        }
      },
    );
  }


  //! This function will help when app will open then we check my subscription is active
  //! If plan is active this will provide true other wise provide false
  //! Base on true/false we move ahead in our app

  Future<bool> _isSubscriptionActive() async {
    final InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition androidAddition = _inAppPurchase.getPlatformAddition<InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition>();
    final QueryPurchaseDetailsResponse response = await androidAddition.queryPastPurchases();

    debugPrint('isSubscriptionActive Error : ${response.error?.message}');

    //! if get an error no plan is active we send false
    if (response.error != null) return false;
    debugPrint('isSubscriptionActive responseList : ${response.pastPurchases}');

    //! if list is empty that mean no plan is active
    //! there for we return false
    if (response.pastPurchases.isEmpty) {
      return false;
    } else {
      response.pastPurchases.forEach(
        (_) {
          debugPrint('status =====> ${_.status}');
          debugPrint('pendingCompletePurchase =====> ${_.pendingCompletePurchase}');
          debugPrint('productID =====> ${_.productID}');
          debugPrint('transactionDate =====> ${_.transactionDate}');
          debugPrint('transactionDate Parsed =====> ${DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(int.parse(_.transactionDate!))}');
          debugPrint('purchaseID ====> ${_.purchaseID}');
        },
      );

      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

**How to use**

Declare provider before use

```
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ...
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SubscriptionProvider()),
        ...
      ],
      child: const Beginning(),
    );
```

In screen where you will make design and make login for buy product.
now consider this is **StatefulWidget**

asume name of StatefulWidget is **SubscriptionPlanScreen** .
so initState() of SubscriptionPlanScreen is

```
  @override
  void initState() {
   
    super.initState();

    //! Here in this screen we will called purchaseInit();
    //! And this is inside initState so it will called one time only
    //! and this will provide products details
    //! we used "WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback" because we want to used context in provider
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (_) {
        //Provider-Value
        final subscription = context.read<SubscriptionProvider>();

        /// Init Store -> Get available product from store
        /// call purchaseInit -> get storeInfo
        subscription.purchaseInit();

        ///! User can listers stream from outside of provider also
        ///! if you want then you can handle from here also
        ///! this same functionality available in [SubscriptionProvider] also
        ///! we don't do from here we do inside [SubscriptionProvider]
        ///! [NOTE] but if you use here then don't used inside provider
        // subscription.subscription.listen(
        //   (event) {
        //     debugPrint('listenCalled');
        //   },
        //   onDone: () {},
        //   onError: (_) {},
        // );
      },
    );
  }
```

Now look **Widget build(BuildContext context)** method of SubscriptionPlanScreen

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final subscriptionProvider = context.watch<SubscriptionProvider>();
    final products = subscriptionProvider.productDetails;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: subscriptionProvider.isLoading
            ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
            : Padding(
                padding: padding,
                child: subscriptionProvider.isAvailable
                    ? Column(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  ///..... your ui ......
                                  // Your button like  ElevatedButton
                                  // show onPressed  login for buy product

                                  CustomButton(
                                    btnHeight: 40,
                                    btnWidth: double.maxFinite,
                                    title: "Continue",
                                    onPressed: () async {
                                      // but any product from products list
                                      await subscriptionProvider.buyProduct(
                                        product: products[0], // pass index base on your logic
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ),

                                  /// Restore your product (if have)

                                  InkWell(
                                    onTap: () => subscriptionProvider.restorePlan(),
                                    splashColor: splashColor,
                                    highlightColor: highlightColor,
                                    child: const Padding(
                                      padding: padding,
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Restore",
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),

                                  /// ....... your ui ........
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    : const Center(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "No any current subscription plan found.",
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 2),
                            Text(
                              "Please try latter",
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Hope this will help you**